# "User memory limit exceeded" when selecting a single feature in a feature collection?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have a feature collection of 18000+ polygons. I would like to get the pixel values of each pixel in every polygon that intersects Landsat imagery. The problem I am currently having is when I try to access one feature in the feature collection, I am getting the "user memory limited exceeded" error. Is this feature collection too much for Earth Engine to handle?

```
var table = ee.FeatureCollection("users/adrianom/SN_Meadows");
var size = table.size();
var fc_list = table.toList(size);
var feature = fc_list.get(0);
print(feature);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.toList(size)` is effectively asking Earth Engine to load everything in the collection into memory at once, because lists (as opposed to collections) always work that way. You should avoid using `toList` whenever possible; Earth Engine is designed to process collections in a streaming fashion and `toList` prevents that from working.

For your example, you can use `var feature = table.first();`

In general, you should usually use `table.filter(...)` to pick the feature(s) you want according to their properties.